# How can I prove this two identities? $\cos^2 x=\frac{1+\cos(2x)}{2}$ and $\sin^2 x=\frac{1-\cos(2x)}{2}$

Tags: geometry, algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

> How can I simply prove the two following equations? $$\cos^2x=\frac{1+\cos(2x)}{2} \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\text{ and }\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\, \sin^2 x=\frac{1-\cos(2x)}{2}$$

I already proven them using two methods:

- $\cos^2x+\sin^2x=1$
- $\text{The Pythagorean theorem:}\, \, \text{BC}^2=\text{AB}^2+\text{AC}^2$

So I'm looking for a proof that doesn't use those two methods. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Differentiate, $\frac{d}{dx} \cos^2 x = - 2\sin x\cos x = - \sin (2x) = \frac{d}{dx} \frac{1+\cos (2x)}{2}$. They coincide in $0$, hence everywhere. Similar for the other.

Comment: @Adobe I find a bit strange when you ask it to prove without the most basic identity in trig. What is your motivation for it?

Comment: @Sawarnik Curiosity, improving proving skills.

Answer (score 1):

Can you use $$\cos(A+B)=\cos A\cos B-\sin A\sin B$$  and $$\sin^2x+\cos^2x=1$$

---

Alternatively, using [Euler's Formula](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Euler%27s_Formula) $$e^{ix}=\cos x+i\sin x$$

$$e^{-ix}=\cos(-x)+i\sin(-x)=\cos x-i\sin x$$

$$\implies \cos x=\frac{e^{ix}+e^{-ix}}2\text{ and }\sin x=\frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{2i}$$

Comment: Right, but to transform that into the posted identity involves the identity $\cos^2 \theta + \sin^2\theta = 1$. The OP doesn't want that in any proof to derive the said identities: "I already proved them using $\cos^2 \theta + \sin^2\theta = 1$..." No need to reinvent the wheel here.

Comment: @amWhy, how about the edited version

Comment: @Adobe, how about the alternative method?

Comment: @labbhattacharjee Yes I can use it, but I'll have to prove the entire sentence if the case.

Answer (score 1):

Repeating the lab bhattacharjee answer. Compute 
$$\cos(x+x)=\cos^2x-\sin^2x$$
adding $\sin^2 x+\cos^2x=1$ to both sides we have
$$\cos(2x)+1=2\cos^2x.$$

Comment: I can't use $\sin^2 x+\cos^2x=1$

Comment: But then i think that use derivatives is useful as in Daniel Fischer comment.